# clang 32 bit addressable ram

Tags: memory, compilation, clang, cross-compiling

I have a RAM which can only be addressed by word (32 bit) not byte level. Is there a way to force clang to only use instructions with memory alignment that access the full word and avoid others that involve a "partial" access with byte level loading/storing.

I have tried using flags like:

```
  -fpack-struct=32
  -fmax-type-align=32
```

but they don't work. The assembly output is still using 8 bit access instructions.